# std::map<int, QStringList> for QAbstractListModel

Tags: qt

There is a container described above, in it the data is present in the form

```
key 1
name "UserTest2"
name "UserTest5"
key 2
name "UserTest3"
key 4
name "UserTest5"
```

If I in the overloaded date method through the FOR in a cycle pass through the container, then all the data is present again.
Now, an index comes from QML (QModelIndex &index) and if I try to get the key using the m_map.find (index) method, then I can get it, but if I ask for the value, I get an error (SIGSEGV).
Can anyone help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: Please show your code rather than trying to describe it -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I'll try to write a quick example. But during the debug, I received such a message. As you can see, the key is valid, but the value is not.                                                       {first = 4, second = <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x88>}